# With Sequelize, how to query a model on a joined model’s property without including it?

Tags: sequelize.js

With models defined like this:

```
Team = sequelize.define 'team',
  name: Sequelize.STRING

User = sequelize.define 'user',
  name: Sequelize.STRING
  foo: Sequelize.INTEGER

Team.hasMany User
User.belongsTo Team
```

how to get all teams containing users where `foo` is equal to `42`, without including users in the result, and without having the same team multiple times in the result, that is, how to generate the following query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT team.id, team.name
FROM team
INNER JOIN user ON user.team_id = team.id
WHERE user.foo = 42
```

**Edit**: The query should be [a raw query](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models/#raw-queries), that is, using the `raw` option of `findAll()`.

Answer (score 0):

To make an inner join use [`required = true`](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/model/#findalloptions-queryoptions-promisearrayinstance) in `include` options of `find*` methods. What about DISTINCT - you can try this hack:

```
Team.findAll({ 
    attributes: ['DISTINCT team.id','team.name'], // hack with distinct
    include: [{ 
        model: User, 
        required: true, // inner join
        attributes: []  // exclude user fields from select
    }] 
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, even with an empty attributes array, this still includes the user’s id column in the query, so DISTINCT is useless. On the other hand, your answer made me realize that with an empty attributes array it actually gives the expected result even if the query isn’t what I want. Sorry, I forgot to mention that it should be a [raw query](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models/#raw-queries), that is, using the `raw` option of `findAll()`, and with that option, matching teams can be multiple times in the result.